# How is Ubuntu software update implemented internally?

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu, update-manager

I need this information so that I can implement same mechanism in distribution of my own software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bit of a vast question but at the highest possible level:

1. Software is packaged as .deb packages and placed into APT repositories
2. APT (Advanced Packaging Tool) collates those repositories and makes searching and installing them (through `dpkg`) possible through utilities such as `apt-get` and `apt-cache`.
3. Applications like the Software Centre and Update Manager front onto APT utilities and libraries.

When something is updated, the package is rebuilt. The control file stores a higher version number and (often) the filename reflects this version too. This is uploaded to the repo and the package index is updated to show the new version.

When a computer (which has this repo) updates its own package list, it grabs all the repos' packages lists and selects the newest available packages (eg `apt-cache policy linux` will usually show multiple versions available) as the "available" one.

When the user does an `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` (through `apt-get` or one of the higher-level graphical tools) the newest version of those packages are downloaded and installed.

Comment: Thx for the overview but by asking above question I meant that first two points are in place in my case. I want to know how 3rd point works and is implemented. How does ubuntu know there is updates in apt repo automatically. So that i can implement the same method and my software will also know that there is updated version available and will update itself. Just like other famous software like vlc, firefox, chrome etc.

Comment: @AashitVerma This is all handled by Ubuntu. You update your repo and any computers that are subscribed to it will pick up the changes (provided your Packages.gz is updated too), usually within 24 hours. Firefox and Chrome don't automatically update in Ubuntu as they do in Windows, they use the same update process as everything else.